# Is it possible to apply validations by `class` in M2 like in M1?

Tags: magento2

I was wondering if it is possible to apply validation to a field in a similar way to M1:

```
Validation.add('validate-email', 'Please enter a valid Gmail address. For example johndoe@gmail.com.', function(v) {
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]*@gmail\.com)$/i.test(v)
})
```

So that this validation would be applied to all fields with the class of `validate-email`.

I am asking because I find that KO validations are really inflexible and I haven't found a way to change anything about them once the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow these steps :

Add this html tag for email field :

```
<input id="InputEmail" class="form-control" type="email" name="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
```

Add this script in your phtml file :

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#Your_Form_Id": {
            "validation": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what should `#Your_Form_Id` be replaced with?

Comment: You need to replace your <form> id

Comment: where do I find this form ID for the checkout?